# JSON JavaScript Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, json, sharepoint

How can I create a hyperlink using date retrieved by JSON/JavaScript?

```
{ "mData": "FileRef" } - here I would like to have a hyperlink instead only text value.
```

Below JavaScript function used by me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function LoadZipCodes(state)
  {
    var call = $.ajax({
      url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('SharePointList')/items?$select=FileRef",
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
      }
    });

    call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
      $('#example').dataTable({
        "bDestroy": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "aaData": data.d.results,
        "aoColumns": [
          { "mData": "FileRef" }
        ]
      });
    });

    call.fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
      alert("Error retrieving Tasks: " + jqXHR.responseText);
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried this `{ "mData": "<a href='some_link'>FileRef</a>" }`

Comment: { "mData": "<a href='some_link'>FileRef</a>" }

It doesn't work...

Comment: then im not sure what you are trying to achieve. by the way you need to replace "some_link" with some actual value. if you could elaborate your question it would be helpful

Comment: My problem is associated with this:

http://summit7systems.com/who-needs-a-data-view-web-part-sharepoint-rest-and-datatables-net/

I just need display value in table generated by JS/JSON as hyperlink to document.

Comment: I mean document like a SharePoint list item for example hyperlink do document: http://moss/sites/SharePoint/ExampleList/ExampleSharePointDocument.xml?OpenIn=Browser

Now I can only get this link as text without option to click.

Comment: where are you getting the link to that document in your code? if you are getting it in your code , you could use that to replace "some_link" with that link in my first comment

Comment: If I have { "mData": "<a href='FileRef'>FileRef</a>" },
I get error http://s10.postimg.org/qoynikncp/image.png

Comment: ofcourse. fileRef is simply a string. its not a variable pointing to your document. you need an actual url. so again i am asking where are you getting the url to that document in your code?

Comment: I get data using this call: var call = $.ajax({
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('ZipCodes')/items?$select=Title,Column2,Column3&$filter
=(Column3 eq '"+state+"')&$top=5000",
type: "GET",


dataType: "json",
headers: {
Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
}

Comment: Author of article http://summit7systems.com/who-needs-a-data-view-web-part-sharepoint-rest-and-datatables-net/

Said me:

Yes, you can have a hyperlink,  but you'll need to iterate through the result set first and set the values in the JSON object to the values you want displayed in the table.